# Apply the same pod disruption budget to multiple services

Tags: kubernetes

I have 10 services (names, myapp1, myapp2, myapp3, etc).
I want to apply the same pod disruption budget to every service (for example max unavailable 1).
The way I read the pdb docs, if I apply a custom tag, I'll create a "metaservice" which it will track for pdbs.

Is there a way to apply 10 identical pdbs to 10 services? (if I create 10 pdb objects, if I decide I want to go from max unavail 1 to max unavail 2, I need to change 10 pbd objects, not one).

jsonnet inheritence/ helm charts, etc to programmatically create the 10 pdbs.